# Is it possible to receive ping answer with a different process/thread using scapy

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, ping, scapy

I want to built and send some ICMP packets with one process and receive the answers on another in order to work with the ICMP echo reply (e.g. sending a traceroute to not reachable hosts).
For this problem i use scapy. I tested it already without multiprocessing and built in scapy methods like `srp1()`/`sr()` or using a socket `s.send(packet)` which were all to slow for my purposes. The `s.send(packet)` variant was the fastest way to simply send the packages but i want to work with the answers and haven't found a way to receive the them.

```
packet = Ether()/IP(dst='192.168.0.0/24')/ICMP()
    packets = [p for p in packet]
    s = conf.L2socket(iface='enp0s3')
    for p in packets:
        s.send(p)
```

So far i tried using one process for sending and one for receiving.

```
def sendICMP():
    print('sending...')
    packet = Ether()/IP(dst='192.168.0.0/24')/ICMP()
    packete = [p for p in packet]
    s = conf.L2socket(iface='enp0s3')
    for p in packete:
        s.send(p)

def recvICMP():
    print('receiving...')
    s = conf.L2socket(iface='enp0s3')
    a = sniff(iface='enp0s3', filter="icmp and src 192.168.0.1", count=256) 
    print(a[0].getlayer(ICMP).type)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=sendICMP)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=recvICMP)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

This doesn't work. Is it a problem sending and listening on the same socket with two processes. Would threading do a better job here? What also came to my mind was that i could use a queue where i could put in the responses from the ICMP requests but i don't know how to do that. Basically i'm looking for a very performant possibility to send and receive lot's of ICMP packets. The order of the answer packages is not really important.

Answer (score 0):

Actually changing the sniff arguments to `a = sniff(iface='enp0s3', filter="icmp", count=0)` does the job. Since the variable `a` is a `scapy.plist.PacketList` you can iterate over it to get the information of every single packet. Accessing ping e.g. information is done as follows:

`a[i].getlayer(ICMP).type` => i = number of the package.